# Deserializing uncertain values in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, return, deserialization

I have a json as deined below ,

```
{
    "ApplicationOne": {
        "Version": "1.0",
        "Owner": "coderClan"
    },
    "ApplicationTwo": {
        "Version": "2.0",
        "Owner": "gamers"
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement a method such that when an application ID (ApplicationOne , ApplicationTwo) is passed as a parameter , the owner will be returned

```
public static string GetOwner(string applicationID)
        {
            string owner = ""; //Deserialized Owner Name
            return owner;
        }
```

The problem I have is that I have no way of being certain of the application ID as that can be changed ? hence I cannot create the POCO classes as below,

```
public class ApplicationOne
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationTwo
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ApplicationOne ApplicationOne { get; set; }
    public ApplicationTwo ApplicationTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Is it still possible to deserialize this ? Would really appreciate an example of how I can implement this

Comment: What do you mean by "can be changed"? Changed where?

Comment: Depends on how it is defined in the file , which means it wil changed from file to file

Comment: Rename `ApplicationOne`  `ApplicationAny` (for example), get rid of the rest and deserialize as: `var appAny = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ApplicationAny>>(json);`. Then you extract by key as  `appAny["ApplicationOne"].Version` and `appAny["ApplicationOne"].Owner`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with *Newtonsoft.Json* using dynamic:

```
dynamic deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var result = deserialized["ApplicationOne"]?.Owner?.ToObject<string>();
```

And the method:

```
public static string GetOwner(string applicationID)
{
     return deserialized[applicationID]?.Owner?.ToObject<string>();
}
```